# Change destination file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an image created with php.

```
<img src="captcha.php" />
```

How can i put this captcha.php in some folder (inc), but the src="captcha.php" stay as it is.

I think htaccess maybe can do that.

Some help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? Can't you just put `/inc/captcha.php` as the source?

Comment: Because i don't want to let everyone know where I have all script files....

Comment: How does that matter? You'd still be exposing the script simply by listing it in the src. If your security depends on mangling URLs, your "security" system is going to be bypassed very quickly. Turn off directory browsing and no one can see what's in the folder from the outside.

Comment: I think you're right... My only think is security and that is why I wanted to change destination. Maybe if i do my homeword with security, i don't need to change anything. Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think this is what you are looking for,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^captcha.php$ /inc/captcha.php
```

Assuming that your "inc" folder and captcha.php file are right at your root level.